# Vue JS - Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__App_vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am a first timer with Vue.js, i am following a tutorial on it on Udemy, but have hit a snag the first time spinning up the app.

I get this error in the console when trying to test my routes.

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__App_vue___default.a is not a constructor
```

It is referencing this line of my code:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
```

> **my entire main.js file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from './App.vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

> **my routes.js file:**

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import Unlocks from './components/unlocks/Unlocks.vue';

export const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home },
    {path: '/unlocks', component: Unlocks }
];
```

any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! Like I said i am a Vue Noob, first day! thanks in advance and please let me know if more info is required!

Answer (score 0):

So my apologies for wasting your time with this! this was a typo on my end!

The problem was on this line:

```
import VueRouter from './App.vue'
```

which needed to be:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```